# js - trigger generic function on space bar press anywhere on document

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, keydown

I have a colour guessing game with six different colour squares and an rgb code at the top of the page. The game works and the game resets via function - resetUI() - when a reset button on the page is clicked.

However, I want to trigger the resetUI function whenever the space bar is pressed. I have the following code, it doesn't throw any errors but it also doesn't work:

```
var body = document.querySelector("body");
body.addEventListener("keydown",function(){
  if(this.key === " "){
    resetUI();
  }
});
```

I am fairly certain my use of "this" is wrong but I can't think of an alternative.

I have searched MDN and stackOverflow but I haven't seen a solution to this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) belongs to the event (which is passed into the event handler), not the body (which is what `this` refers to).

The next problem you will have is when you add an input or textarea to the page and anytime the user put a space into the input it will run your function.. You can check against the target to make sure the input isn't receiving the keystroke before you fire your function..

```js
var body = document.querySelector("body");
body.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
  var isInput = ~["TEXTAREA", "INPUT"].indexOf(e.target.tagName);
  if(e.key === " " && !isInput){
    // resetUI();
    console.log("u clicked spacebar, and it wasn't in an input");
  }
});
```

```html
<input />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have lot of unnecessary code. And you should receive the `event` object from callback function to check against which key got pressed.

To check spacebar you shouldn't check against `" "` instead you have to check the keyCode of event.

```js
document.body.onkeydown = function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 32){
             console.log("space bar pressed");
             resetUI();
        }
    }
```